# insert values from a popup component to another box component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, insert, react-hooks, components

i am trying to insert inside box with list items of unordered list and this component is called 'ProductList'. the code for this component is  listed below:

```
import React from 'react'
    import './ProductList.css'
    
    function ProductList(setAddProduct) {
        
        
        return (
            <div className="box">
                <ul>
                    <li>S.N.</li>
                    <li>Product Name</li>
                    <li>Category</li>
                    <li>Stock</li>
                    <li>Status</li>
                    <li>Action</li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        )
    }

export default ProductList
```

when i give all the values and information inside this popup component called AddProduct and click save button then i want the popup close and the information transferred to above box component.

```
import React from 'react'
import Dropdown from './Dropdown'
import './AddProduct.css'
import ProductList from './ProductList'

function AddProduct() {
    const { useState } = React;
    const [AddProduct, setAddProduct] = useState();

    return (
        <div className="box">
            <h1>Add Product</h1>
            <p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name"></input>
           <Dropdown />
            </p>
            
           
           <p>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Stock"></input>
           </p>

           <div>
           <button className="btn2" onClick={() => setAddProduct(AddProduct)}>Save</button>
           </div>
           {AddProduct && <ProductList setAddProduct={setAddProduct} />}
          
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddProduct
```

there is already usestate for the pop up in home js as below:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Dropdown from './Dropdown'
import Radiobutton from './Radiobutton'
import AddProduct from './AddProduct'


function Home() {
    const { useState } = React;
    const [showAddProduct, setShowAddProduct] = useState(false);

    

    return (
        <div>
            <Radiobutton />
            
        <div className="product">
            <Dropdown />
            
            
            <button className="btn1" onClick={() => setShowAddProduct(!showAddProduct)}>
                &#x2b;AddProduct</button> 
        </div>
        {showAddProduct && <AddProduct setShowAddProduct={setShowAddProduct} />} 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Can you tell me where is the state of popup based on which you are opening or closing the popup?

Comment: you gave the solution early which i think would work but i didn't get to test can i get the help

Comment: Go and follow the answer and let me know after that!

Comment: the pop is opening like usual but the information from the popup does not get inserted in the box.

Comment: {AddProduct && <ProductList setAddProduct={setAddProduct} />}
In above code you are passing the the props as "setAddProduct" so receive in the "box" component as "props.setAddProduct" and it will work. Just console it like this to check! 
You are using "ProductList(setAddProduct)" so access like this:
 setAddProduct.setAddProduct in ProductList function.

Comment: this is not working and i check the console also  its giving me the error saying cant call second call back function its recommend me to use effect hook. i also used usestate hook for the popup show in home.js so mayeb the error !? i update the code for home js so you can get more infromation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set a state for popup to open or close it(boolean).
Then you have to make function and which will be called on click. Set the state of popup(false) and set the AddProduct.
Once it is set send it to "Box" and from box receive them as props. Here is the possible workflow.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import Dropdown from './Dropdown'
    import './AddProduct.css'
    import ProductList from './ProductList'
    
    function AddProduct() {
        const { useState } = React;
        const [AddProduct, setAddProduct] = useState();
        const [popup,setPopUp] = useState(true);

    
    //This is the function you have to set false popup state to close popup 
    //and send data to ProductList(box)
    
    const handlePopUpCloseAndSendData = () =>{
      setAddProduct(AddProduct); //to save data
      setPopUp(false); //to close popup
    }
        return (
            <div className="box">
                <h1>Add Product</h1>
                <p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name"></input>
               <Dropdown />
                </p>
               <p>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Stock"></input>
               </p>
               <div>
               <button className="btn2" onClick={
                  () =>handlePopUpCloseAndSendData() //function which will set States
                  }>Save</button>
               </div>
               {AddProduct && <ProductList setAddProduct={AddProduct} />} 
              
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default AddProduct;
```